# Find all values of $x$ where the determinant equals 0

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

$$\det\begin{bmatrix}x & x & x & x & x\\a & x & x & x & x\\a & a & x & x & x\\ a &a&a& x& x\\a&a&a&a&x\end{bmatrix} = 0$$

Having this matrix I am trying to find all the values of $x$ that fulfill the above equation. I tried it with the long way of computing the cofactors but that just takes too much time. Is there another more efficient way?

Comment: Hint: look for obvious values first, e.g. $x=0,x=a$. Then do row/column operations to make it simpler.

Comment: Yes did that. I am looking for a more generic solution.

Comment: That matrix can be fairly quickly reduced to an upper triangular matrix using elementary row operations.  The determinant of an upper triangular matrix is relatively easy to compute, and elementary row operations play nice with determinants.

Comment: $x(x-a)^4=0$ I get this. But this is only true for $x\ne0$. Does that seem right? Because all we get is $x=a$.

Comment: @HarryTouloupas For $x=0$, the determinant is already $0$, so now you are getting another value of $x$ (namely, $x=a$) for which the determinant is $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly $x=0$ is one of those values. Now, if $x\ne 0$, then

\begin{align}
\det\begin{pmatrix}x & x & x & x & x\\a & x & x & x & x\\a & a & x & x & x\\ a &a&a& x& x\\a&a&a&a&x\end{pmatrix}
&=x\det\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\a & x & x & x & x\\a & a & x & x & x\\ a &a&a& x& x\\a&a&a&a&x\end{pmatrix} \\
&=x\det\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\0 & x-a & x-a & x-a & x-a\\0 & 0 & x-a & x-a & x-a\\ 0 &0&0& x-a& x-a\\0&0&0&0&x-a\end{pmatrix} \\
&=x(x-a)^4
\end{align}

Comment: @darij grinberg: regarding your edit, the assumption that $x\ne 0$ is necessary in order to factor the $x$ out of the first row of the matrix.  It might be pedantic, but it is correct.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thanks for editing in those det's. I thought I wrote {vmatrix} but I obviously did write {pmatrix}.

Comment: I did remark the obvious value $\;x=0\;$ just for clearity: the calculations still are *almost*  correct but it would be way more confusing if $\;x=0\;$ would be accepted. That's all. I always tell my students to distinguish out any obvious value in some equation of any kind, if just for simplicity and clearity. And the second matrix would be pretty incorrect if $\;x=0\;$ is admited: that row of $\;1's\;$ couldn't be there...

Answer (score 1):

Perform: $C_1-C_2, C_2-C_3,C_3-C_4,C_4-C_5$ (column operations). These preserve the determinant, so

$$\begin{vmatrix}x & x & x & x & x\\a & x & x & x & x\\a & a & x & x & x\\ a &a&a& x& x\\a&a&a&a&x\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & x\\a-x & 0 & 0 & 0 & x\\0 & a-x & 0 & 0 & x\\ 0 &0&a-x& 0& x\\0&0&0&a-x&x\end{vmatrix}$$

Now you can expand along any row (for example first row) and use the idea of upper/lower triangular (or better yet diagonal) matrix. To get
$$\det=x\begin{vmatrix}a-x & 0 & 0 & 0 \\0 & a-x & 0 & 0\\ 0 &0&a-x& 0\\0&0&0&a-x\end{vmatrix}=x(a-x)^4.$$

So $\det=0$ for $x=0,a$ only.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the $n \times n$ generalization of this.
Write your matrix as $A = a {\bf 1 1}^T + (x-a) U = (x-a)(a (x-a)^{-1} \bf{1 1}^T U^{-1} + I) U$, where $U$ is the matrix with all $1$'s on and above the diagonal and $0$'s elsewhere, and $\bf 1$ the column vector of all $1$'s.  By Sylvester's determinant identity and the fact that $\det(U)=1$, 
$$\det(A) = (x-a)^n \det(I + a (x-a)^{-1} {\bf 1}^T U^{-1} {\bf 1})$$
  Now $U^{-1} \bf 1$ is the column vector with last entry $1$ and all others $0$, so
$I + a(x-a)^{-1} {\bf 1}^T U^{-1} {\bf 1} = 1 + a (x-a)^{-1} = x/(x-a)$ (a $1 \times 1$ matrix, whose determinant is its entry).  Thus $$\det(A) = x (x-a)^{n-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Expanding my comment, a reasonable approach might be to reduce the problem to something a little more tractable via elementary row operations.  Suppose that $A$ is a matrix.

- Let $A_\text{swap}$ be the matrix obtained by swapping two rows of $A$.  Then $\det(A_{\text{swap}}) = -\det(A)$.
- Let $A_{\text{scale}}$ be the matrix obtained by scaling one row of $A$ by some constant $C$.  Then $\det(A_{\text{scale}}) = \frac{1}{C} \det(A)$.
- Let $A_{\text{add}}$ be the matrix obtained by adding a row of $A$ to a different row of $A$.  Then $\det(A_{\text{add}}) = \det(A)$.

So, if we use elementary row operations to reduce your matrix to something more tractable (and we keep track of those operations), we are in business.  So, try the following:
\begin{align}
A = \begin{pmatrix} x & x & x & x & x \\
 a & x & x & x & x \\
 a & a & x & x & x \\
 a & a & a & x & x \\
 a & a & a & a & x \end{pmatrix}
&\implies
\begin{pmatrix} x & x & x & x & x \\
 -a & -x & -x & -x & -x \\
 a & a & x & x & x \\
 -a & -a & -a & -x & -x \\
 a & a & a & a & x \end{pmatrix} \\
&\implies \begin{pmatrix} x-a & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & a-x & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & x-a & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & a-x & 0 \\
 a & a & a & a & x \end{pmatrix} =: A'.
\end{align}
In the first reduction, we multiply the second and third rows by $-1$.  This has no net effect on the determinant, since it amounts to multiplying the determinant by $-1$ twice.  In the last step, we are just adding row $j+1$ to row $j$ for each $j=1,2,3,4$; this also doesn't change the determinant.  In other words, we have
$$ \det(A) = \det(A'). $$
But $A'$ is a lower triangular matrix, so the determinant is the product of the terms on the diagonal.  In other words
$$ \det(A') = (x-a)(a-x)(x-a)(a-x)x = x(x-a)^4. $$
This is zero only when $x \in \{0, a\}$.